# Reading 7 segment digits using Paddle OCR

Tags: image-processing, ocr, paddle-paddle, paddleocr

I am trying to read the 7 segment display using Paddle OCR, sometimes it reads correctly otherwise it reads poorly given the image is clear and visible to read

For example:
This image is clear and readable:

[image]

but the output of the image using paddle OCR is `8L1100`

It reads this image perfectly:

[image]

Output is: `240141`

I did try some preprocessing on the image by grayscale, blurring and using opening and closing on the image, but the same problem persists.

Comment: `8L1100` looks like it rotated the image by 180 degrees

Comment: Please edit your question, and include a reproducible code sample. Please note that there is no generic solution that is going to work for all the images you are not showing us (we can only address the posted images).

Answer (score 1):

For the first image the OCR has flipped the text - (think BOOBS on a calculator). You can pass `use_angle_cls=False` argument to PaddleOCR.